# C# How to XOR bytes as text file is read into a string

Tags: c#

I need to prevent some kids from modifying json text files and putting "fartface" in them. My current code gets a string from the text file like so:

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(basePath + "jsontxt"))
{
    string s = file.ReadToEnd();
```

I can apply an XOR to my jsontxt files which is sufficient to prevent malicious fart jokes, but in my wpf C# app I'm not sure how to implement the byte XOR as the file is read into a string.

Comment: this question does not make sense

Comment: @SamIam - I agree.  Fart jokes are _always_ funny.

Comment: -1:  There's no attempt at the actual problem described.

Answer (score 4):

Try to get the string as a byte array and simply XOR each byte with some secret key:

```
Byte[] byteString;
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(basePath + "jsontxt"))
{
   Byte secretByte = 125;
   string s = file.ReadToEnd();
   byteString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
   foreach(Byte b in byteString)
   {
      b ^= secretByte;
   }
}
//here save stream
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to subclass StreamReader because I'm a complete moron with c#.

Comment: don't be so critical. programming is not so hard as drive a car.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with this idea.

First, you will find it very difficult to come up with an XOR value that, when applied, will consistently produce a readable character. In that case, your file then becomes a binary file, not a text file.

Second, assuming you could come up with a way to guarantee a readable file, that doesn't stop people from modifying it.

If you want to encrypt your files, use a real encryption technique. Or at least convert your string to a byte array, XOR the bytes, and write the file as binary. To read it back, read the file as binary into a `byte[]` (i.e. `File.ReadAllBytes`), XOR the bytes, and then convert that byte buffer to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [System.IO.CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), Microsoft's stream decorator for reading/writing encrypted streams. Simple!

To read the encrypted text, something like this suffices:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadEncryptedTextFile( string path , byte[] key , byte[] iv , Encoding encoding )
{
  string value ;
  using ( Stream s = File.OpenRead(path) )
  using ( SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create() )
  using ( ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor( key , iv ) )
  using ( CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( s , transform , CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )
  using ( TextReader sr = new StreamReader(cs,encoding))
  {
      string line ;
      while ( null != ( line = sr.ReadLine() ) )
      {
          yield return line ;
      }
  }
}
```

To write the encrypted text, something like this:

```
static void WriteEncryptedTextFile ( IEnumerable<string> lines , string path , byte[] key , byte[] iv , Encoding encoding )
{
  using ( Stream             s         = File.OpenWrite(path) )
  using ( SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create() )
  using ( ICryptoTransform   transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor( key , iv ) )
  using ( CryptoStream       cs        = new CryptoStream( s , transform , CryptoStreamMode.Write ) )
  using ( TextWriter         tw        = new StreamWriter( cs , encoding ) )
  {
    foreach ( string line in lines )
    {
      tw.WriteLine( line ) ;
    }
  }
  return ;
}
```

You might want to dial in the specific algorithm you use (and each algorithm has requirements about `key` and `iv` size).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are trying to implement some type of verification to make sure the file was not modified.  Why not just get the hashcode of your string and check against that?

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(basePath + "jsontxt"))
{
    string s = file.ReadToEnd();
}
if (verificationCode != s.GetHashCode())
{
    // Malicious fart joke eminent!
}
```

Your verificationCodes could be produced easily by running a Powershell script on your directory of files... you don't mention how you are storing your XOR values to check against but you could have the script write to a location you can check against...

```
$files = Get-Item "C:\test\*.js"

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $text = Get-Content $file
    $file.BaseName +" "+ $text.GetHashCode()
}
```

Comment: `Object::GetHashCode()` is not a checksum.

Comment: @MattEnright Of course not... the OP is clearly not looking for a checksum...  he wanted an extremely simple way to see if the files had changed.